# Calculating mean of Pandas dataframe in iterations

Tags: python, file, csv, file-io, pandas

I have a huge CSV file like this

Code, Duration

101, 32

205, 111

722, 33

205, 67

722, 33

205, 241

Now I am reading file in chunk as file is pretty big. How to calculate avg duration for each code and save it to CSV file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by code and store the count and sum of `'Code'`,`'Duration'`; something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def f(g):
    return pd.DataFrame({'count': [g.shape[0]], 'sum': [g['Duration'].sum()]})

reader = pd.read_csv('data.csv',chunksize=2)
acc = pd.DataFrame({})
for chunk in reader:
    acc = acc.add(chunk.groupby('Code').apply(f).reset_index(level=1,drop=True),fill_value=0)

acc['avg'] = acc['sum']/acc['count']
print acc

acc.to_csv('avg_codes.csv',cols=['avg'],index_label='Code')
```

Output in terminal:

```
      count  sum         avg
Code                        
101       1   32   32.000000
205       3  419  139.666667
722       2   66   33.000000
```

Output in file **avg_codes.csv**:

```
Code,avg
101,32.0
205,139.66666666666666
722,33.0
```

Comment: I get exception

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Where code is 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
from numpy.random import randn

def f(g):
    return pd.DataFrame({'count': [g.shape[0]], 'sum': [g['Duration'].sum()]})
    
reader = pd.read_csv("Sample.csv", iterator=True,chunksize=1000, usecols=[1,5])

acc = pd.DataFrame({})
for chunk in reader:
    acc = acc.add(chunk.groupby('To').apply(f).reset_index(level=1,drop=True),fill_value=0)

acc['avg'] = acc['sum']/acc['count']
print acc

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby.size` and `groupby.sum` for every dataframe, and then reduce them to the result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

c = np.random.randint(100, 10000, 100000)
d = np.random.rand(100000)

df = pd.DataFrame({"c":c, "d":d})
r1 = df.groupby("c").d.mean()

counts = []
sums = []
for i in range(10):
    df2 = df[i*10000:(i+1)*10000]
    g = df2.groupby("c").d
    counts.append(g.size())
    sums.append(g.sum())

from functools import partial
func = partial(pd.Series.add, fill_value=0)
r2 = reduce(func,  sums) / reduce(func, counts).astype(float)
```

You can also use following code for the final step:

```
r3 = pd.concat(sums, axis=1).sum(axis=1) / pd.concat(counts, axis=1).sum(axis=1).astype(float)
```

to check the result:

```
print np.allclose(r1, r2)
print np.allclose(r1, r3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not `pandas` but it works and is memory efficient.

```
import csv
from collections defaultdict

code_counts = defaultdict(int)
code_durations = defaultdict(int)
with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # discard header row
    for code, duration in reader:
        code_counts[code] += 1
        code_durations[code] += int(duration)    
code_averages = {code: code_duratons[code] / float(code_counts[code]) for code in code_counts}
```